# Удаление значений из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, есть два списка со значениями:

```py
X = 'something'
Y = 123
List1 = [1,"big","small",X,Y]
List2 = [1,X,Y]

result = ["big","small"]
```

Какой метод использовать, чтобы получить этот результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если порядок следования элементов не важен, то можно просто вычесть множества, это будет сложность O(n):

```py
X = 'something'
Y = 123
List1 = [1,"big","small",X,Y]
List2 = [1,X,Y]
result = list(set(List1) - set(List2))
print(result)
```

Если же порядок элементов нужно сохранить, то можно так, хотя это и менее оптимально - сложность O(n<sup>2</sup>):

```py
result = [x for x in List1 if x not in List2]
```

Впрочем, этот вариант тоже можно ускорить до O(n):

```
Set2 = set(List2)
result = [x for x in List1 if x not in Set2]
```

Comment: Множества можно использовать только если все элементы списка хешируемы. Хороший, но не очень универсальный способ